# Apache Ignite - [PDOException] SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: odbc, ignite, pdo-odbc

I have setup apache ignite, loaded data into ignite from Java app and can query using rest apis. I need to query it from PHP so

I am trying to connect to Apache Ignite from PHP using pdo_odbc. I have,

i) Installed ODBC driver manager - http://www.unixodbc.org/

ii) Built ODBC driver  http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/odbc-driver#section-building-on-linux

iii) installed Ignite ODBC driver http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/odbc-driver#section-installing-on-linux,

iv) configured dsn, http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.8/docs/connecting-string#configuring-dsn  using

odbcinst -j

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/me/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[Apache Ignite]
Description=Apache Ignite
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so
DriverODBCVer=03.00
FileUsage=0
UsageCount=1
```

cat /etc/odbc.ini

```
[Apache Ignite]
Description=Apache Ignite
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so
DriverODBCVer=03.00
FileUsage=0
UsageCount=1
```

cat /home/me/.odbc.ini

```
[Apache Ignite]
Description=Apache Ignite
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so
DriverODBCVer=03.00
FileUsage=0
UsageCount=1
```

v) installed pdo_odbc,

```
sudo apt install php5.6-odbc
```

It shows in phpinfo.

vi) enabled OdbcConfiguration using

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml");
IgniteConfiguration iCfg = ignite.configuration();
OdbcConfiguration odbcCfg = new OdbcConfiguration();
iCfg.setOdbcConfiguration(odbcCfg);
```

vii)

```
$ignite = $dbh = new \PDO('odbc:Apache Ignite');
$ignite->prepare('select * from Person');
```

I am still getting this exception.

```
  [PDOException]                                                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[01000] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so' : file not found
```

Update: LD_LIBRARY_PATH already has /usr/local/lib
ls /usr/local/lib | grep  libignite-binary-1.8.0.16166.so.0

```
libignite-binary-1.8.0.16166.so.0
libignite-binary-1.8.0.16166.so.0.0.0
```

ldd /usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe68521000)
libignite-binary-1.8.0.16166.so.0 => not found

Comment: if ldd says `libignite-binary-1.8.0.16166.so.0` was not found, then you don't have directory with `libignite-binary-1.8.0.16166.so.0` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried run `ldd /usr/local/lib/libignite-odbc.so`? It seems like there are some unresolved dependencies. Maybe you need to add them to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks Updated question